# Cannot install weblogic

Tags: weblogic, bea

I am trying to install weblogic on one of my local environment. 
But when trying to install the weblogic application, it said java.exe or javaw.exe has stopped working
and the program crashes. Any idea on how to fix above issue?

Below is the java path in Weblogic folder

> C:\bea\jdk131_14\bin

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic server does not support Java 13.
You must use Java 8 (or 7) with WebLogic server 12c.